# HTML: JQuery how to use JQuery to get data-dk-dropdown-value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to make selection options and I need to change the class of selected item which is selected (On mouse over), so basically I'm not a web-developer so I really don't know how to achieve this, I was trying to research for this, but I didn't succeed.

So I need two things, once the user mouse over the selected opinion the class of `li` changes to `dk_option_current` and once the user clicks on the selection I can do some future stuff, I really don't know how to achieve this, I may be using Javascript, but that's just a lot of work to do my myself.

```html
<div class="dk_container dk_theme_black dk_open" id="dk_container_arrow-tip" tabindex="1" style="display: block;">
  <a class="dk_toggle" style="width: 129px;">
    <span class="dk_label">TopHat 3D 60g</span>
  </a>
  <div class="dk_options">
    <ul class="dk_options_inner">
      <li class="dk_option_current"><a data-dk-dropdown-value="1">TopHat 3D 20g</a></li>
      <li class=""><a data-dk-dropdown-value="2">TopHat 3D 70g</a></li>
      <li class=""><a data-dk-dropdown-value="4">TopHat 3D 100g</a></li>
      <li class=""><a data-dk-dropdown-value="6">Brass 3D 70g</a></li>
      <li class=""><a data-dk-dropdown-value="7">Brass 3D 100g</a></li>
      <li class=""><a data-dk-dropdown-value="9">Brass Bullet 70g</a></li>
      <li class=""><a data-dk-dropdown-value="10">Brass Bullet 100g</a></li>
      <li class=""><a data-dk-dropdown-value="12">Steel Field 70g</a></li>
      <li class=""><a data-dk-dropdown-value="13">Steel Field 100g</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do it using `:hover` instead of adding a class.

Comment: I know I can use it, but I need to only change the class on mouseover, but when the user clicks it should set the other label text to the value which user selected

Comment: Your question was not specific about the second part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It you really would prefer to use `mouseover` instead of using CSS `:hover` you can do it like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".dk_options_inner li").mouseover(function() {
      $(".dk_options_inner li").removeClass("dk_option_current");
      $(this).addClass("dk_option_current");
   });
   $(".dk_options_inner li").click(function() {
      $(".dk_options_inner li").removeClass("dk_option_current selected");
      $(this).addClass("dk_option_current selected");
      $(".dk_label").text($(this).text());
   });
});
```

```css
.dk_option_current, .selected {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dk_container dk_theme_black dk_open" id="dk_container_arrow-tip" tabindex="1" style="display: block;"><a class="dk_toggle" style="width: 129px;"><span class="dk_label">TopHat 3D 20g</span></a>
  <div class="dk_options">
    <ul class="dk_options_inner">
      <li class="dk_option_current selected"><a data-dk-dropdown-value="1">TopHat 3D 20g</a></li>
      <li class=""><a data-dk-dropdown-value="2">TopHat 3D 70g</a></li>
      <li class=""><a data-dk-dropdown-value="4">TopHat 3D 100g</a></li>
      <li class=""><a data-dk-dropdown-value="6">Brass 3D 70g</a></li>
      <li class=""><a data-dk-dropdown-value="7">Brass 3D 100g</a></li>
      <li class=""><a data-dk-dropdown-value="9">Brass Bullet 70g</a></li>
      <li class=""><a data-dk-dropdown-value="10">Brass Bullet 100g</a></li>
      <li class=""><a data-dk-dropdown-value="12">Steel Field 70g</a></li>
      <li class=""><a data-dk-dropdown-value="13">Steel Field 100g</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I need, but can you add one thing that once the text changes, the selected object will have the selected class on

Comment: It doesn't work, `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript">

    $(".dk_options_inner li").mouseover(function(){
        $(".dk_options_inner li").removeClass("dk_option_current");
        $(this).addClass("dk_option_current");
    });

    $(".dk_options_inner li").click(function(){
        $(".dk_options_inner li").removeClass("dk_option_current");
        $(this).addClass("dk_option_current");
        $(".dk_label").text($(this).text());
    });
</script>`

Comment: @DzITC I've added the additional requirement so the selected object stays selected with an additional class and wrapped the function in a document.ready() function in order to work once the page and jquery is loaded.

Comment: Can we continue in the chat please?